# Not present notification view in landscape mode

Tags: ios, landscape, portrait

İn my app support portrait mode.But i have one view controller which is landscape.When I get notification in this view (landscape) root view not present my portrait notificationViewController but while i 'm in portrait viewcontroller, notification view controller presenting in app delegate.

Thanks